# Is there any way to check if a Periodic task is already scheduled with GcmNetworkManager

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I want to scheduled a Periodic task with Gcm Network manager only if it is not already scheduled. So is there any way to check if a Periodic task is already scheduled with GcmNetworkManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GcmNetworkManager` does not offer anything like that. Instead you could use [`GcmNetworkManager.cancelTask()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager#cancelTask%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmTaskService%3E%29) to cancel all existing tasks and schedule yours just after.

Alternatively implementing [`Task.isUpdateCurrent()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task#isUpdateCurrent%28%29) might have a similar effect, although the documentation for this is quite sparse:

> **Returns:** Whether or not this task will update a pre-existing task in the scheduler queue.